# Why doesn't Option have a fold method?

Tags: scala, dictionary, fold, scala-option

I wonder why `scala.Option` doesn't have a method `fold` like this defined:

```
fold(ifSome: A => B , ifNone: => B)
```

equivalent to

```
map(ifSome).getOrElse(ifNone)
```

Is there no better than using `map` + `getOrElse`?

Comment: You really want `else: => B`--and actually it shouldn't be called `else` since that's a reserved word.  But anyway, you want the option-is-empty case to be passed by name so you get lazy evaluation.

Comment: Edited to fix the type signatures to the canonical fold.

Comment: I'm far from a scalaz mastermind -- actually a scala beginner --, but I actually prefer map and getOrElse.  I find `fold` to be just something else to to learn.  Maybe I need my mind renewed.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654004/implementing-iftrue-iffalse-ifsome-ifnone-etc-in-scala-to-avoid-if-and which shows (near the end) an ifSome/ifNone pimp for Option.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do:

```
opt foldLeft (els) ((x, y) => fun(x))
```

or

```
(els /: opt) ((x,y) => fun(x))
```

*(Both solutions will evaluate* `els` *by value, which might not be what you want. Thanks to [Rex Kerr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247533/rex-kerr) for pointing at it.)*

**Edit:**

But what you really want is Scalaz’s [catamorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism) `cata` (basically a `fold` which not only handles the `Some` value but also maps the `None` part, which is what you described)

```
opt.cata(fun, els)
```

defined as (where `value` is the pimped option value)

```
def cata[X](some: A => X, none: => X): X = value match {
  case None => none
  case Some(a) => some(a)
}
```

which is equivalent to `opt.map(some).getOrElse(none)`.

Although I should remark that you should only use cata when it is the ‘more natural’ way of expressing it. There are many cases where a simple `map`–`getOrElse` suffices, especially when it involves potentially chaining lots of `map`s. (Though you could also chain the `fun`s with function composition, of course – it depends on whether you want to focus on the function composition or the value transformation.)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this uses Option -> Iterable implicit conversion and the `els` argument isn't by-name so it evaluates every time.

Comment: This has not been mentioned in the original specification.

Comment: Agreed--it wasn't mentioned.  But it's a good thing to have for most any control structure like this.

Comment: Isn't `opt.foldLeft(els)((_,elem) => fun(elem))` actually how your first example should read, @Debilski? I say this since you want to apply `foo` to the caller of `foldLeft` (opt) rather than `els`.  https://gist.github.com/kman007us/8485124 Is that true? (Additionally, do you find it clearer to use `_` rather than `y` for an un-used argument?)

Comment: @KevinMeredith True, the accumulator is the first parameter, not the second, so `fun` should be applied over the second one.

Comment: This answer seems redundant now and should be removed

Answer (score 75):

I personally find methods like `cata` that take two closures as arguments are often overdoing it. Do you really gain in readability over `map` + `getOrElse`? Think of a newcomer to your code: What will they make of

```
opt cata { x => x + 1, 0 }
```

Do you really think this is clearer than

```
opt map { x => x + 1 } getOrElse 0
```

In fact I would argue that neither is preferable over the good old

```
opt match {
  case Some(x) => x + 1
  case None => 0
}
```

As always, there's a limit where additional abstraction does not give you benefits and turns counter-productive.

Comment: As per the edit, there's only one function parameter for this particular call. Named arguments provides another way to make things readable: `opt.fold(ifSome = _ + 1, ifNone = 0)`. If the function is defined earlier, which makes it usable elsewhere, I find this particularly nice: `opt.fold(f, 0)`.

Comment: A more readable alias for OptionW.cata is e.g. `opt some { _ + 1 } none { 0 }`. This and `fold` and `cata` also have the benefit of enforcing s and n return the same type, whereas you might get an unintended type with e.g. `(None: Option[Int]) getOrElse ("2") // returns an Any`. Pointed out by [Learn You a Scalaz](https://github.com/jrwest/learn_you_a_scalaz/blob/master/1-intro.md).

Comment: The problem for me is that IntelliJ marks the map-getOrElse pattern as an issue and suggests using fold instead.

Answer (score 41):

It was finally added [in Scala 2.10](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option), with the signature `fold[B](ifEmpty: => B)(f: A => B): B`.

Unfortunately, this has a common negative consequence: `B` is inferred for calls based only on the `ifEmpty` argument, which is in practice often more narrow. E.g. (a correct version is already in the standard library, this is just for demonstration)

```
 def toList[A](x: Option[A]) = x.fold(Nil)(_ :: Nil)
```

Scala will infer `B` to be `Nil.type` instead of desired `List[A]` and complain about `f` not returning `Nil.type`. Instead, you need one of

```
 x.fold[List[A]](Nil)(_ :: Nil)
 x.fold(Nil: List[A])(_ :: Nil)
```

This makes `fold` not quite equivalent to corresponding `match`.

Answer (score 19):

As mentioned by Debilski, you can use Scalaz's `OptionW.cata` or `fold`. As Jason commented, named parameters make this look nice:

```
opt.fold { ifSome = _ + 1, ifNone = 0 }
```

Now, if the value you want in the `None` case is `mzero` for some `Monoid[M]` and you have a function `f: A => M` for the `Some` case, you can do this:

```
opt foldMap f
```

So,

```
opt map (_ + 1) getOrElse 0
```

becomes

```
opt foldMap (_ + 1)
```

Personally, I think `Option` should have an `apply` method which would be the catamorphism. That way you could just do this:

```
opt { _ + 1, 0 }
```

or

```
opt { some = _ + 1, none = 0 }
```

In fact, this would be nice to have for all algebraic data structures.