# Implementing ifTrue, ifFalse, ifSome, ifNone, etc. in Scala to avoid if(...) and simple pattern matching

Tags: scala, match, control-flow

In Scala, I have progressively lost my Java/C habit of thinking in a control-flow oriented way, and got used to go ahead and get the object I'm interested in first, and then usually apply something like a `match` or a `map()` or `foreach()` for collections. I like it a lot, since it now feels like a more natural and more to-the-point way of structuring my code.

Little by little, I've wished I could program the same way for conditions; i.e., obtain a Boolean value first, and then `match` it to do various things. A full-blown `match`, however, does seem a bit overkill for this task.

Compare:

```
obj.isSomethingValid match {
  case true => doX
  case false => doY
}
```

vs. what I would write with style closer to Java:

```
if (obj.isSomethingValid)
  doX
else
  doY
```

Then I remembered Smalltalk's `ifTrue:` and `ifFalse:` messages (and variants thereof). Would it be possible to write something like this in Scala?

```
obj.isSomethingValid ifTrue doX else doY
```

with variants:

```
val v = obj.isSomethingValid ifTrue someVal else someOtherVal

// with side effects
obj.isSomethingValid ifFalse {
  numInvalid += 1
  println("not valid")
}
```

Furthermore, could this style be made available to simple, two-state types like `Option`? I know the more idiomatic way to use `Option` is to treat it as a collection and call `filter()`, `map()`, `exists()` on it, but often, at the end, I find that I want to perform some `doX` if it is defined, and some `doY` if it isn't. Something like:

```
val ok = resultOpt ifSome { result =>
  println("Obtained: " + result)
  updateUIWith(result) // returns Boolean
} else {
  numInvalid += 1
  println("missing end result")
  false
}
```

To me, this (still?) looks better than a full-blown `match`.

I am providing a base implementation I came up with; general comments on this style/technique and/or better implementations are welcome!

Comment: What exactly is wrong with an `if` statement? You can either use this simple, familiar control structure that is used extensively everywhere in every language, or you can create a gimmicky abstraction that is a mental speedbump for any new developer and doesn't provide any advantage over `if` in the first place.

Comment: There's `if` for Booleans, but what about simple `match`es for `Option`?

Comment: For `Option`, there is `getOrElse`.

Comment: So, a different way to treat each situation. A more consistent treatment with ifTrue/ifFalse and ifSome/ifNone thus sounds good to me…

Comment: See also this discussion on the mailing list: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/3496

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First: we probably cannot reuse `else`, as it is a keyword, and using the backticks to force it to be seen as an identifier is rather ugly, so I'll use `otherwise` instead.

Here's an implementation attempt. First, use the pimp-my-library pattern to add `ifTrue` and `ifFalse` to `Boolean`. They are parametrized on the return type `R` and accept a single by-name parameter, which should be evaluated if the specified condition is realized. But in doing so, we must allow for an `otherwise` call. So we return a new object called `Otherwise0` (why 0 is explained later), which stores a possible intermediate result as a `Option[R]`. It is defined if the current condition (`ifTrue` or `ifFalse`) is realized, and is empty otherwise.

```
class BooleanWrapper(b: Boolean) {
  def ifTrue[R](f: => R) = new Otherwise0[R](if (b) Some(f) else None)
  def ifFalse[R](f: => R) = new Otherwise0[R](if (b) None else Some(f))
}
implicit def extendBoolean(b: Boolean): BooleanWrapper = new BooleanWrapper(b)
```

For now, this works and lets me write

```
someTest ifTrue {
  println("OK")
}
```

But, without the following `otherwise` clause, it cannot return a value of type `R`, of course. So here's the definition of `Otherwise0`:

```
class Otherwise0[R](intermediateResult: Option[R]) {
  def otherwise[S >: R](f: => S) = intermediateResult.getOrElse(f)
  def apply[S >: R](f: => S) = otherwise(f)
}
```

It evaluates its passed named argument if and only if the intermediate result it got from the preceding `ifTrue` or `ifFalse` is undefined, which is exactly what is wanted. The type parametrization `[S >: R]` has the effect that `S` is inferred to be the most specific common supertype of the actual type of the named parameters, such that for instance, `r` in this snippet has an inferred type `Fruit`:

```
class Fruit
class Apple extends Fruit
class Orange extends Fruit

val r = someTest ifTrue {
  new Apple
} otherwise {
  new Orange
}
```

The `apply()` alias even allows you to skip the `otherwise` method name altogether for short chunks of code:

```
someTest.ifTrue(10).otherwise(3)
// equivalently:
someTest.ifTrue(10)(3)
```

Finally, here's the corresponding pimp for `Option`:

```
class OptionExt[A](option: Option[A]) {
  def ifNone[R](f: => R) = new Otherwise1(option match {
    case None => Some(f)
    case Some(_) => None
  }, option.get)
  def ifSome[R](f: A => R) = new Otherwise0(option match {
    case Some(value) => Some(f(value))
    case None => None
  })
}

implicit def extendOption[A](opt: Option[A]): OptionExt[A] = new OptionExt[A](opt)

class Otherwise1[R, A1](intermediateResult: Option[R], arg1: => A1) {
  def otherwise[S >: R](f: A1 => S) = intermediateResult.getOrElse(f(arg1))
  def apply[S >: R](f: A1 => S) = otherwise(f)
}
```

Note that we now also need `Otherwise1` so that we can conveniently passed the unwrapped value not only to the `ifSome` function argument, but also to the function argument of an `otherwise` following an `ifNone`.

Comment: Mind blown. One of the most beautiful pieces of code I've seen in my life :'(

Answer (score 6):

You may be looking at the problem too specifically.  You would probably be better off with the pipe operator:

```
class Piping[A](a: A) { def |>[B](f: A => B) = f(a) }
implicit def pipe_everything[A](a: A) = new Piping(a)
```

Now you can

```
("fish".length > 5) |> (if (_) println("Hi") else println("Ho"))
```

which, admittedly, is not quite as elegant as what you're trying to achieve, but it has the great advantage of being amazingly versatile--any time you want to put an argument first (not just with booleans), you can use it.

Also, you already can use options the way you want:

```
Option("fish").filter(_.length > 5).
  map (_ => println("Hi")).
  getOrElse(println("Ho"))
```

Just because these things could take a return value doesn't mean you have to avoid them.  It does take a little getting used to the syntax; this may be a valid reason to create your own implicits.  But the core functionality is there.  (If you do create your own, consider `fold[B](f: A => B)(g: => B)` instead; once you're used to it the lack of the intervening keyword is actually rather nice.)

---

Edit: Although the `|>` notation for pipe is somewhat standard, I actually prefer `use` as the method name, because then `def reuse[B,C](f: A => B)(g: (A,B) => C) = g(a,f(a))` seems more natural.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! Indeed, this pipe operator is much more general than my proposal. I find the lack of intermediate keyword causes a diminished readability, especially when two blocks follow each other… I can easily add an apply() method to my OtherwiseX objects and forward it to otherwise, or the other way round. As you wrote: getting used to the native syntax of Option takes time… I still find it rather cryptic at times, if nested multiple times (plus, I have to check each time if it's actually a collection or an Option), whereas ifX and otherwise seem clearer to me.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't just use it like this:

```
val idiomaticVariable = if (condition) { 
    firstExpression
  } else { 
    secondExpression 
  }
```

?

IMO, its very idiomatic! :)

Comment: Well, like ryeguy's comment, this works with if(boolean), but what about Option, then?

Comment: Personally I see no difference between `value match { case A => doA; case B => doB() }` with only two variants and `if (cond) doA else doB;` statement. Morevover, `if` looks much more familiar to many programmers and it expresses intent: a kind of binary decision. Thus, its ok to write `if (opt.isDefined) doA else doB` in case you have some actions not related to `opt` and can't `opt map` or `opt flatMap` to these actions. To summarize, see no problem here...