# How to check for null in a single statement in scala?

Tags: scala, null, inline

In my scala code:

```
QueueManager.add(getObject)
```

where `getObject` is a method that returns an object of type `QueueObject`.

```
def getObject : QueuObject = {
    val response = //some response
    return response
}
```

Is there a way I can check for the response being null, while adding the QueueObject? I know I can do this:

```
if (getObject != null)
    QueueManager.add(getObject)
```

But I do not wish to add a level of indentation. Is there an operator that does that inline?

Thanks.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Try to avoid using `null` in Scala. It's really there only for interoperability with Java. In Scala, use `Option` for things that might be empty. If you're calling a Java API method that might return `null`, wrap it in an `Option` immediately.

```
def getObject : Option[QueueObject] = {
  // Wrap the Java result in an Option (this will become a Some or a None)
  Option(someJavaObject.getResponse)
}
```

Note: You don't need to put it in a `val` or use an explicit
`return` statement in Scala; the result will be the value of
the last expression in the block (in fact, since there's only one statement, you don't even need a block).

```
def getObject : Option[QueueObject] = Option(someJavaObject.getResponse)
```

Besides what the others have already shown (for example calling `foreach` on the `Option`, which might be slightly confusing), you could also call `map` on it (and ignore the result of the map operation if you don't need it):

```
getObject map QueueManager.add
```

This will do nothing if the `Option` is a `None`, and call `QueueManager.add` if it is a `Some`.

I find using a regular `if` however clearer and simpler than using any of these "tricks" just to avoid an indentation level. You could also just write it on one line:

```
if (getObject.isDefined) QueueManager.add(getObject.get)
```

or, if you want to deal with `null` instead of using `Option`:

```
if (getObject != null) QueueManager.add(getObject)
```

*edit* - Ben is right, be careful to not call `getObject` more than once if it has side-effects; better write it like this:

```
val result = getObject
if (result.isDefined) QueueManager.add(result.get)
```

or:

```
val result = getObject
if (result != null) QueueManager.add(result)
```

Answer (score 13):

```
Option(getObject) foreach (QueueManager add)
```

Comment: Cool, I hadn't realized you could just write `(QueueManager add)` instead of `(QueueManager add _)`.

Answer (score 12):

If it instead returned `Option[QueueObject]` you could use a construct like `getObject.foreach { QueueManager.add }`.  You can wrap it right inline with `Option(getObject).foreach ...` because `Option[QueueObject](null)` is `None`.

Answer (score 6):

Although I'm sure @Ben Jackson's asnwer with `Option(getObject).foreach` is the preferred way of doing it, I like to use an `AnyRef` pimp that allows me to write:

```
getObject ifNotNull ( QueueManager.add(_) )
```

I find it reads better.

And, in a more general way, I sometimes write

```
val returnVal = getObject ifNotNull { obj =>
  returnSomethingFrom(obj)
} otherwise {
  returnSomethingElse
}
```

... replacing ifNotNull with ifSome if I'm dealing with an `Option`. I find it clearer than first wrapping in an option and then pattern-matching it.

(For the implementation, see [Implementing ifTrue, ifFalse, ifSome, ifNone, etc. in Scala to avoid if(...) and simple pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654004/implementing-iftrue-iffalse-ifsome-ifnone-etc-in-scala-to-avoid-if-and) and the `Otherwise0`/`Otherwise1` classes.)

Comment: Ok, but why would you want to make your own version of `if` / `else` (renaming `else` to `otherwise`...). It's an interesting exercise but it doesn't win you anything in practice and might make your code more confusing for others to read.

Comment: @Jesper I agree in general — although I find that `getObject ifNotNull ( QueueManager.add(_) )` is less confusing than `Option(getObject).foreach(QueueManager.add(_))`. `foreach` especially would tend to make me think there could be several objects being processed, and I always have to scan back to find out it's actually an `Option`. It would be great if `Option` could have well-named aliases for those methods.

Comment: Philippe yes, I don't like the trick with `foreach` either, it's indeed a bit misleading when used on an `Option`; the simplest is just to write it with a regular `if`.