# Idiomatic way to check for parameter initialization

Tags: scala, idioms

I have a variable `param` which has to be initialized at runtime.

Then, I have a part of the code which implements the following:

```
if (param has been initialized)
     ...do something...
else
     print error and exit
```

What is the most idiomatic way to do this in Scala?

So far I have used `Option[X]` in this way:

```
var param : Option[TheType] = None
...
val param_value : TheType = x getOrElse {println("Error"); null}
```

But, since I have to return `null` it seems dirty.

How should I do it?

Comment: Could you provide more context? Is it a method parameter? If not providing it is an error, why allow not providing it to begin with?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check for null in a single statement in scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740906/how-to-check-for-null-in-a-single-statement-in-scala)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply `map` or `foreach` over it:

```
param.foreach { param_value =>
  // Do everything you need to do with `param_value` here
} getOrElse sys.exit(3)  # Param was empty, kill the program
```

You can also use the `for` comprehension style:

```
for {
  param_value <- param
} yield yourOperation(param_value)
```

The upside of this is that if your calling code is expecting to do something with `param_value` as a return value from `yourMethod` you will encode the possibility of `param_value` not existing in your return type (it will be an `Option[TheType]` rather than a potentially `null` `TheType`.)

Answer (score 2):

I might me wrong but it seems to me that the use of [Future](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) would fit with your problem:  Instead of explicitly checking whether your required `param_value` has been initialized and finish the program if not, you could make your resource dependent code to execute when the resource has been rightly initialized:

```
val param: Future[TheType] = future {
      INITIALIZATION CODE HERE
}

param onFailure {
    case e => println("Error!");
}

param onSuccess {
    case param_value: TheType => {
        YOUR BUSINESS CODE HERE
    }
}
```