# Could Scala's “if … else” have been implemented as a library function?

Tags: scala, if-statement, keyword, control-flow

I'm wondering if `if … else` could have been implemented in `Predef` with special compiler treatment, in a similar way to what's being done with `classOf[A]`: the definition is in `Predef`, the implementation is filled in by the compiler.

Granted, many people would find reassuring to know that an `if` is always an `if`, and an `else` is always an `else`, no matter the context. However, defining `else` as a method on the result type of `if` would remove it from the list of keywords, and allow library designers to define their own `else` methods. *(I know I can use any keyword as an identifier with backticks, but something like `` `else` `` just looks awful in code.)* Such methods could be useful in cases discusses in situations such as [this one, discussed on the mailing list](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/3496), where people are forced to use `otherwise` when defining methods that actually should be named `else`. (Also discussed on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654004/implementing-iftrue-iffalse-ifsome-ifnone-etc-in-scala-to-avoid-if-and/5654007#5654007) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945904/what-are-your-most-useful-own-library-extensions/5947797#5947797).)

So:

- Would such an approach be possible, even in theory, or does it break some fundamental principle in Scala?
- What would the downsides be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand your question, but you can already implement `if ... else ...` as a library function. Consider this:

```
class If[A](condition: =>Boolean)(ifBlock: =>A) {
  def els(elseBlock: =>A):A = condition match {
    case true => ifBlock
    case false => elseBlock
  }
}

new If(2==3)(
  println("equal")
) els (
  println("not equal")
)
```

Of course this doesn't do *exactly* what `if ... else ...` does, but with some polishing I think it would. I once implemented a very simple interpreter for a language that had pattern matching built in with `if ... else ...` being implemented in much the same way I did here.

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is "yes"; branching logic on some predicate can be implemented as a library function.

It's worth pointing out that, as Viktor Klang and others have noted, if/else is essentially folding a boolean. Folding is something we do frequently - sometimes it's clear and explicit, and sometimes not.

```
// Either#fold is explicit
scala> Left[String, Double]("fail") fold(identity, _ + 1 toString)
res0: java.lang.String = fail

scala> Right[String, Double](4) fold(identity, _ + 1 toString)
res1: java.lang.String = 5.0
```

Folding an option cannot be done explicitly, but we do it all the time.

```
// Option has no fold - wont compile!
Some(5) fold(1+, 0)

// .. but the following is equivalent and valid
scala> Some(5) map(1+) getOrElse(0)
res3: Int = 6
```

Branching logic on a boolean is also a fold, and you can pimp Boolean accordingly. Note the use of by-name parameters to achieve lazy evaluation. Without this feature, such an implementation wouldn't be possible.

```
// pimped Boolean - evaluates t when true, f when false
class FoldableBoolean(b: Boolean) {
  def fold[A](t: => A, f: => A) =
    if(b) t else f
}

implicit def b2fb(b: Boolean) = new FoldableBoolean(b)
```

Now we can fold Booleans:

```
scala> true fold("true!", "false")
res24: java.lang.String = true!

scala> false fold("true!", "false")
res25: java.lang.String = false
```

Comment: Option has fold method as of 2.10

Answer (score 3):

Not just `if-else`, but *any* language feature can be overridden in a branch of the language known as "Scala Virtualized"

https://github.com/TiarkRompf/scala-virtualized

This forms the basis of the Delite project at Stanford PPL, and is also at the heart of the research being funded by Scala's EU grant. So you can reasonably expect it to be part of the core language at some point in the future.

Comment: Great to know this! This would indeed looks like the next logical step… I'm looking forward to the future :-)

Answer (score 3):

*Any* object-oriented language (or *any* language with runtime polymorphism) can implement conditionals as a library feature, since method dispatch already is a more general form of conditional anyway. Smalltalk, for example, has absolutely no conditionals whatsoever except for method dispatch.

There is no need for any kind of compiler magic, except maybe for syntactic convenience.

In Scala, it would look maybe a little bit like this:

```
trait MyBooleanLike {
  def iff[T <: AnyRef](thenn: => T): T
  def iffElse[T](thenn: => T)(els: => T): T
  def &&(other: => MyBoolean): MyBoolean
  def ||(other: => MyBoolean): MyBoolean
  def nott: MyBoolean
}

trait MyTruthiness extends MyBooleanLike {
  def iff[T](thenn: => T) = thenn
  def iffElse[T](thenn: => T)(els: => T) = thenn
  def &&(other: => MyBoolean) = other
  def ||(other: => MyBoolean) = MyTrue
  def nott = MyFalse
}

trait MyFalsiness extends MyBooleanLike {
  def iff[T](thenn: => T): T = null.asInstanceOf[T]
  def iffElse[T](thenn: => T)(els: => T) = els
  def &&(other: => MyBoolean) = MyFalse
  def ||(other: => MyBoolean) = other
  def nott = MyTrue
}

abstract class MyBoolean extends MyBooleanLike

class MyTrueClass extends MyBoolean with MyTruthiness {}
class MyFalseClass extends MyBoolean with MyFalsiness {}

object MyTrue extends MyTrueClass {}
object MyFalse extends MyFalseClass {}
```

Just add a little implicit conversion:

```
object MyBoolExtension {
  implicit def boolean2MyBoolean(b: => Boolean) =
    if (b) { MyTrue } else { MyFalse }
}

import MyBoolExtension._
```

And now we can use it:

```
object Main extends App {
  (2 < 3) iff { println("2 is less than 3") }
}
```

[Note: my type-fu is rather weak. I had to cheat a little bit to get this to compile within a reasonable timeframe. Someone with a better understanding of Scala's type system may want to fix it up. Also, now that I look at it, 8 classes, traits and objects, two of them abstract, seems a little over-engineered ;-) ]

Of course, the same is true for pattern matching as well. Any language with pattern matching doesn't need other kinds of conditionals, since pattern matching is more general anyway.

[BTW: This is basically a port of [this Ruby code](http://joergwmittag.github.com/b001e/) I wrote a couple of years ago for fun.]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very nice proof of concept! I realize this can be done like this. My question was rather if the current form of `if ... else´ could have been implemented, as is, as a library function. I think you and Kim Stebel have shown that it is.