# How can I write f(g(h(x))) in Scala with fewer parentheses?

Tags: scala, coding-style, syntax, functional-programming

Expressions like

```
ls map (_ + 1) sum
```

are lovely because they are left-to-right and not nested. But if the functions in question are defined outside the class, it is less pretty.

Following [an example](http://talkingcode.co.uk/2009/03/11/abstract-type-members-augmenting-scala-classes/) I tried

```
final class DoublePlus(val self: Double) {
    def hypot(x: Double) = sqrt(self*self + x*x)
}

implicit def doubleToDoublePlus(x: Double) =
    new DoublePlus(x)
```

which works fine as far as I can tell, other than

1. A lot of typing for one method
2. You need to know in advance that you want to use it this way

Is there a trick that will solve those two problems?

Comment: What is wrong with defining hypot in a utility object and then use as `hypot(3,4)`? Seems like the best choice here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can call `andThen` on a function object:

```
(h andThen g andThen f)(x)
```

You can't call it on methods directly though, so maybe your `h` needs to become `(h _)` to transform the method into a partially applied function. The compiler will translate subsequent method names to functions automatically because the `andThen` method accepts a `Function` parameter.

You could also use the [pipe operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654004/implementing-iftrue-iffalse-ifsome-ifnone-etc-in-scala-to-avoid-if-and/5654270#5654270) `|>` to write something like this:

```
x |> h |> g |> f
```

Answer (score 2):

Enriching an existing class/interface with an implicit conversion (which is what you did with `doubleToDoublePlus`) is all about API design when some classes aren't under your control. I don't recommend to do that lightly just to save a few keystrokes or having a few less parenthesis. So if it's important to be able to type `val h = d hypot x`, then the extra keystrokes should not be a concern. (there may be object allocations concerns but that's different).

The title and your example also don't match:

`f(g(h(x)))` can be rewritten as`f _ compose g _ compose h _ apply x` if your concern is about parenthesis or `f compose g compose h apply x` if f, g, h are *function objects* rather than *def*.

But `ls map (_ + 1) sum` aren't nested calls as you say, so I'm not sure how that relates to the title. And although it's *lovely* to use, the library/language designers went through a lot of efforts to make it easy to use and under the hood is not simple (much more complex than your *hypot* example).

Comment: Well they *are* nested calls in a sense: the result of each step becomes the `this` argument to the next call. In other languages this nesting would be explicit. My issue is that while whether a particular argument is a `this` argument is functionally not very significant, it is only because of this fact that you get nice calling syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
def fgh (n: N) = f(g(h(n))) 
val m = fgh (n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this, observe how a is provided:

def compose[A, B, C](f: B => C, g: A => B): A => C = (a: A) => f(g(a))

basically like the answer above combine the desired functions to a intermediate one which you then can use easily with map.

Answer (score 0):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, the standard library provides the chaining operation [`pipe`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/util/ChainingOps.html#pipe[B](f:A=%3EB):B) which can be used to convert/pipe a value with a function of interest.

Using multiple `pipe`s we can thus build a `pipeline` which as mentioned in the title of your question, minimizes the number of parentheses:

```
import scala.util.chaining._

x pipe h pipe g pipe f
```