# Fold on Option, instead of `if maybeT.isNone()`

Tags: java, functional-programming, functional-java

This is a similar question to [Why doesn't Option have a fold method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328007/why-doesnt-option-have-a-fold-method), but for functional-java.

I want to perform some side-effect if an option is None. Is there something I can use other than `if maybeT.isNone()`?

I'm thinking along the lines of `Option<B> optionA.fold(Effect<Unit> none, F<A, B> some)`.

Is there something that already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [option method](https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/blob/master/core/src/main/java/fj/data/Option.java#L131)

```
public final <B> B option(final P1<B> b, final F<A, B> f) {
  return isSome() ? f.f(some()) : b._1();
}
```