# Scala Option: map vs Pattern Matching

Tags: scala

While dealing with `Option` in Scala what are the things I should be considering to decide whether to map or patten match? For example, if I have `Option[MyClass]`, I can deal with it the following ways:

```
def getList(myOptionInstance: Option[MyClass]): List[String] =
  myOptionInstance map (...) getOrElse(List.empty[String])
```

or

```
def getList(myOptionInstance: Option[MyClass]): List[String] = myOptionInstance match {
  case Some(mySomeInstance) => .....
  case None => List.empty[String]
}
```

When will I choose one over the other?

Comment: In situations like this I prefer the pattern match because it is generally more readily comprehensible and generates significantly more efficient code (no `Function1`s).

Comment: Other option: `myOptionInstance.toList flatMap (...)`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I second @rarry: `fold` is the preferred way to deal with this.

Some prefer pattern matching because it's "cool" (whatever it means) and sometimes easier to read.

I try to avoid using `getOrElse` because it does not force you to use the same type for the default value as the type wrapped in your `Option`:

```
def getOrElse[B >: A](default: ⇒ B): B
```

So you can write:

```
val v = Some(42).getOrElse("FortyTwo")
```

Here `v` has type `Any`. It's very easy to see the problem with such a stupid example but sometimes it's not as obvious and can lead to issues.

While `fold`:

```
def fold[B](ifEmpty: ⇒ B)(f: (A) ⇒ B): B
```

It forces you to return the same type for both branches.

```
scala> Some(42).fold("fortyTwo")(v => v)
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: String
              Some(42).fold("fortyTwo")(v => v)
```

Comment: For some reason this option didn't even occur to me and thanks for pointing out pretty important difference regarding type checks between ```fold``` & ```getOrElse```.

Comment: Option.fold was only added in Scala 2.10, so many people haven't realized it's there yet. Thanks for pointing it out, as well as the great warning about the return types with getOrElse.

Comment: BTW: `x => x` is already defined in `Predef` under the name `identity`.

Comment: I have to disagree here—in cases where you have a legit default value, `getOrElse(v)` is better than `fold(v)(identity)`. The clarity about intention trumps the possibility of an unwanted lubbing to `Any` (which should quickly and safely crash in any reasonable context, anyway).

Comment: The question was about mapping on Some or getting a default value for None. Identity was just for my example.

Comment: @vptheron: Agreed! If you're mapping (and on 2.10+) you should definitely be using `fold`. But a categorical "don't use `getOrElse`" (which is how I got here) isn't good advice.

Comment: getOrElse can also be used to throw Exception, when some expected values not provided, when dealing with JSON REST API.

Answer (score 8):

Pattern matching is :

- slightly more efficient
- not anal about subtypes (in this case @rarry had to add a type hint)
- easier to read
- endorsed by Martin Oderksy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5332657/578101

Answer (score 1):

I would go for this:

```
myOptionInstance.fold(Nil: List[String])(...)
```