# How to specify default value when extracting Option from Option case class

Tags: scala

If I have a case class defined as:

```
case class Foo(bar: Option[String])
```

and a variable `baz: Option[Foo]`, what's the most idiomatic way to extract `bar` from `baz` while providing a default value like an empty string?

Right now, I have

```
baz.fold("")(_.bar.getOrElse(""))
```

but having the empty string in there twice makes me think there's a better way.

Comment: Do *not* use `getOrElse`. See my answer to a previous question for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923600/scala-option-map-vs-pattern-matching/21936653#21936653

Comment: I actually never noticed that `getOrElse` didn't force you to use the same type that's inside the `Option`. Why was it designed that way?

Comment: This is due to the covariance of the type parameter A in `Option[+A]`. There are a lot of resources to read more about that, one example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584830/covariant-type-t-occurs-in-contravariant-position

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
baz.flatMap(_.bar).getOrElse("")
```

Or per @vptheron's comment:

```
baz.flatMap(_.bar).fold("")(identity)
```

Comment: `x => x` is already defined in `Predef` under the name `identity`.

Comment: @vptheron's comments about `getOrElse` are well taken, but I actually prefer the first solution because I think the intention is clearer.