# How to implement maxBy with multiple max in Scala

Tags: scala

I need a maxBy that returns all max values in case of equality.

Here is the signature and a first implementation :

```
def maxBy[A, B](as: Seq[A])(f: A => B)(implicit cmp: Ordering[B]) : Seq[A] = 
  as.groupBy(f).toList.maxBy(_._1)._2
```

Example :

```
maxBy(Seq(("a", "a1"),("a", "a2"),("b", "b1"),("b", "b2")))(_._1)
res6: Seq[(String, String)] = List(("b", "b1"), ("b", "b2"))
```

Updated with @thearchetypepaul comment

```
  def maxBy[A, B](l: Seq[A])(f: A => B)(implicit cmp: Ordering[B]) : Seq[A] = {
    l.foldLeft(Seq.empty[A])((b, a) =>
      b.headOption match {
        case None => Seq(a)
        case Some(v) => cmp.compare(f(a), f(v)) match {
          case -1 => b
          case 0 => b.+:(a)
          case 1 => Seq(a)
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

Is there a better way ?

Comment: Since you have a working answer already, and you haven't identified any shortcomings in your solution that make it unsuitable for you, this is a better fit for CodeReview.

Comment: Yes.  foldLeft. Add the element to the acc if equal, replace acc with Seq(element) if element greater otherwise leave acc unchanged. Linear,one traverse, doesn't build groups of all the non-maximal elements.   Not in front of a computer with Scala so not tested.

Comment: With my head still spinning from reading Functional Programming in Scala, is there any value in representing the result as a Monad - say a trait Contenders with implementations Winner(winner: A) and Tie(winners: Seq[A])?

Comment: I'd try to cache the result of `f(v)`, so to not repeatedly call `f` on the same value many times.

Comment: And `b` can be `None` only the first time through. So check for `l.isEmpty` once outside the `foldLeft` then `l.tail.foldLeft(l.head){...}` and the outer match isn't needed. Then make the accumulator  a pair of the list so far, and `f(v)` so you don't have to recalculate `f(v)` each time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(1) [`Ordering#compare`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.math.Ordering) promises to denote the three possible results by a negative, positive, or zero number, not -1, 1, or 0 necessarily.

(2) `Option#fold` is [generally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923600/scala-option-map-vs-pattern-matching) (though not universally) considered to be more idiomatic than pattern matching.

(3) You are calling `f` possibly multiple times per element.  `TraversableOnce#maxBy` used to do this before it was [fixed](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/ece18346582ffccb6d05b48b647ba5439aa2cca3) in 2.11.

(4) You only accept `Seq`. The Scala library works hard to use `CanBuildFrom` to generalize the algorithms; you might want to as well.

(5) You can use the syntactic sugar `B : Ordering` if you would like.

(6) You prepend to the `Seq`. This is faster than appending, since prepending is O(1) for `List` and appending is O(n). But you wind up with the results in reverse order. `foldRight` will correct this. (Or you can call `reverse` on the final result.)

If you want to allow the use of `CanBuildFrom`,

```
def maxBy[A, Repr, That, B : Ordering](elements: TraversableLike[A, Repr])(f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, A, That]): That = {
  val b = bf()
  elements.foldLeft(Option.empty[B]) { (best, element) =>
    val current = f(element)
    val result = best.fold(0)(implicitly[Ordering[B]].compare(current, _))
    if (result > 0) {
      b.clear()
    }
    if (result >= 0) {
      b += element
      Some(current)
    } else {
      best
    }
  }
  b.result
}
```

If you want to work with `TraversableOnce`,

```
def maxBy[A, B : Ordering](elements: TraversableOnce[A])(f: A => B): Seq[A] = {
  elements.foldRight((Option.empty[B], List.empty[A])) { case (element, (best, elements)) =>
    val current = f(element)
    val result = best.fold(0)(implicitly[Ordering[B]].compare(current, _))
    if (result > 0) {
      (Some(current), List(element))
    } else {
      (best, if (result == 0) element +: elements else elements)
    }
  }._2
}
```

Comment: The `bf` parameter should be implicit, right ?
And `TraversableOnce#maxBy` doesn't seem to call f multiple times : https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L232. BTW, thanks for such a complete answer !

Comment: @YannMoisan, yes implicit. And, yes, `maxBy` appears to have been changed in 2.11. https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/ece18346582ffccb6d05b48b647ba5439aa2cca3. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

if the dataset is small the performance shouldn't concern you that much
and you can just **sort**, **reverse**, and **takeWhile**.

```
def maxBy[A,B:Ordering](l:List[A], f: A => B): List[A] = {
   l.sortBy(f).reverse match {
      case Nil    => Nil
      case h :: t => h :: t.takeWhile(x => f(x) == f(h))
   }
}
```

where the `f` should be an isomorphism on A.
and you can also save `f(h)` before comparison